# Nginx Rewrite Rule : Stuck in a Looping

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I need to redirect one URL depends on cookie value in my Nginx Server.

URL 1: www.example.com/en_us/ne_item.html

URL 2: www.example.com/en_us/ne_item.html?dir=desc&order=n_fr_date

Only on that page if the user cookie (**new_item_val** ) value is more than 2, I need to trigger the redirect.

```
    set $CHEAD S;

    if ($request_uri ~* "([^/]*$)" ) {
    set  $last_path_component  $1;}

           if ($last_path_component ~* 'ne_item.html') {
           set $THEAD  G; }

           if ($http_cookie ~* "new_item_val=2") {
             set $CHEAD "${THEAD}O";
           }

if ($CHEAD = GO) {
return 301 $default_store_code/ne_item.html?dir=desc&order=n_fr_date
           }
```

Facing Problem: Too Many Redirect. Instead of ne_item.html if i use another page , its working fine.

Comment: Check out these two questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2936329/nginx-redirect-if-cookie-present and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29278910/nginx-redirect-a-user-based-on-cookie-for-a-specific-url-only

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a duplicate (links provided)

Comment: I have checked tow answers. My Problem is a little bit different from them.You can see my 2 urls first portion is same and their rewrite url is different. As i mention if i use different URL its working fine .

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. You said "that page" after listing two URLs. You refer to "new_item_val" but it's not defined anywhere. Your question cannot be answered. Please edit it to be more clear. I suspect you mean "I would like to redirect within Nginx if the value stored in a Cookie is great than a given number". I suspect the best answer may be that you should do this in your application: Nginx is a web server, it's not made to run complex logic.